# Adding items to a ComboBox that is added to userform during run time

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a combo box to a user form which will be created at run time , the problem I am facing is to add items to the combo box? Not able to figure out where the mistake would be. Thanks.

```
    Function addComboBox(ByRef TempForm As Object, ByVal controlType As String, 
ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal strCaption As String, ByVal strValues As String)

     Dim NewComboBox As MSforms.ComboBox
     Dim arr As Variant
     Dim i As Integer

     Set NewComboBox = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.ComboBox.1")
      arr = Split(strValues, ";")


        With NewComboBox
                .Name = strCaption & "_" & controlType & "_" & pos
                .Top = 20 + (12 * pos)
                .Left = 100
                .Width = 150
                .Height = 12

        End With



      For i = 0 To UBound(arr)

       NewComboBox.AddItem arr(i)

      Next i

    End Function
```

Comment: A simplified version runs for me and fills the combobox.  I do get a runtime error on the TempForm's "Designer" property and have to change the line to `Set NewComboBox = TempForm.Controls.Add("forms.ComboBox.1")`.  I everything working for you except that there's nothing in the combobox?  If so, are you sure arr is populated?

Comment: Hi Doug, I am able to see the combo box on the form, except no items aee populated, and I verified that arr is being populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the word Designer

Try this (**Tried And Tested**)

```
Set NewComboBox = TempForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Try this. (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim TempForm As Object
    Dim Ret

    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

    Ret = addComboBox(TempForm, "CBox", 1, "MyCombo", "1;2;3;4")

    VBA.UserForms.Add(TempForm.Name).Show
End Sub

Function addComboBox(ByRef TempForm As Object, ByVal controlType As String, _
ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal strCaption As String, ByVal strValues As String)

    Dim NewComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim n As Long, nLines As Long, i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set NewComboBox = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    arr = Split(strValues, ";")


    With NewComboBox
        .Name = strCaption & "_" & controlType & "_" & pos
        .Top = 20 + (12 * pos)
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 12
    End With

    n = 2

    With TempForm
        nLines = .CodeModule.CountOfLines
        .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + 1, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
            .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + n, "    " & _
            NewComboBox.Name & ".AddItem " & arr(i)
            n = n + 1
        Next i
        .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + n, "End Sub"
    End With
End Function
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**MORE FOLLOWUP**

> Thanks for the solution , In case if I have to call addComboBox more than once, i.e to add two or more combo boxes , UserForm_Initialize sub will be created more than once, which is problem again. – Vikram

In such a scenario you have to check if the `UserForm_Initialize` proc exists and then parse it. See the code below. I have added a new optional parameter `S` to your function. I am using that to place the combos one below the other.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim TempForm As Object
    Dim Ret

    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

    Ret = addComboBox(TempForm, "CBox", 1, "MyCombo", "1;2;3;4")

    Ret = addComboBox(TempForm, "CBox1", 1, "MyCombo1", "5;6;7;8", 20)

    Ret = addComboBox(TempForm, "CBox2", 1, "MyCombo2", "9;10;11;12", 40)

    VBA.UserForms.Add(TempForm.Name).Show
End Sub

Function addComboBox(ByRef TempForm As Object, ByVal controlType As String, _
ByVal pos As Integer, ByVal strCaption As String, ByVal strValues As String, _
Optional s As Long)

    Dim NewComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim n As Long, nLines As Long, i As Long, uInitLine As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim MyModule As Object

    Set NewComboBox = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
    arr = Split(strValues, ";")

    With NewComboBox
        .Name = strCaption & "_" & controlType & "_" & pos
        .Top = 20 + (12 * pos) + s
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 12
    End With

    '~~> Connect to the code module of the Userform
    Set MyModule = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(TempForm.Name).CodeModule

    '~~> Check if there is a procedure called UserForm_Initialize
    On Error Resume Next
    uInitLine = MyModule.ProcStartLine("UserForm_Initialize", 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    With TempForm
        '~~> UserForm_Initialize Found
        If uInitLine > 0 Then
            nLines = uInitLine + 2: n = 0
            For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + n, "    " & _
                NewComboBox.Name & ".AddItem " & arr(i)
                n = n + 1
            Next i
        Else
            n = 2

            nLines = .CodeModule.CountOfLines

            .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + 1, "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
            For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + n, "    " & _
                NewComboBox.Name & ".AddItem " & arr(i)
                n = n + 1
            Next i
            .CodeModule.InsertLines nLines + n, "End Sub"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

**SCREENSHOT (Of Userform)**

[image]

**SCREENSHOT (Of Userform Code)**

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddharth- when I remove "designer" I get a run time error ,which says object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: What are you passing for `ByRef TempForm As Object` in the function?

Comment: Dim TempForm As Object                                                                                                                                                  Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

Comment: Thanks for the solution , In case if I have to call addComboBox more than once, i.e to add two or more combo boxes ,  UserForm_Initialize sub will be created more than once, which is problem again.

Comment: Yup in that case, you will have to tweak the code little... Few minutes. I have closed excel. Let me get back to you shortly.

Comment: quick question. Would you be adding anything else besides the combobox at runtime?

Comment: No I mean anything where you have to put something in the "UserForm_Initialize" events

Comment: No .. not in UserForm_Initialize

Comment: Ok I can think of two ways 1) Create optional parameters in the function so that you can create multiple combos in one go 2) Parse the Userform Initialize code. I am pushing off for dinner. Will look at this when I come back.

Comment: I would like to add one combo box to the form in one function call